# Debian keeps grabbing packages from sid despite no sid in /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: debian, apt

I have a machine with Debian Lenny installed. Somehow, when I do apt-get update, I receive this output:

```
sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny Release.gpg [1034B]
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/contrib Translation-en_US
Get:2 http://mirror.yandex.ru sid Release.gpg [836B]
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/non-free Translation-en_US
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/volatile Release.gpg
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/volatile/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/volatile/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/volatile/non-free Translation-en_US
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/updates Release.gpg
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/updates/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/updates/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirror.yandex.ru sid/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny Release     
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/volatile Release
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/updates Release
Hit http://mirror.yandex.ru sid Release                             
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/main Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/contrib Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/non-free Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/volatile/main Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/volatile/contrib Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/volatile/non-free Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/updates/main Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://mirror.yandex.ru sid/main Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/updates/contrib Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/updates/non-free Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/main Packages
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/contrib Packages
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/non-free Packages
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/volatile/main Packages
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/volatile/contrib Packages
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/volatile/non-free Packages
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/updates/main Packages
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/updates/contrib Packages                 
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/updates/non-free Packages                
Hit http://mirror.yandex.ru sid/main Sources/DiffIndex                      
Fetched 1870B in 2s (833B/s)                          
Reading package lists... Done
```

The most strange thing, my /etc/apt/sources.list file looks like this:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian lenny main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates main contrib non-free
```

How I can rid of sid mirror being thrown in?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, in addition to /etc/apt/sources.list there is also /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory, that allows you to have additional package lists thrown in. In my case, I have

```
$ ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 94 2010-12-16 12:15 sid.list
```

which was apparently added by my VDS provider for some reason.

According to man,

> The /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory provides a way to add sources.list entries in separate files. The format is the same as for
>   the regular sources.list
>          file. File names need to end with .list and may only contain letters (a-z and A-Z), digits (0-9), underscore (_), hyphen (-) and
>   period (.) characters.
>          Otherwise they will be silently ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're in a chroot environment, verify with something like this:

```
[ "$(stat -c %d:%i /)" != "$(stat -c %d:%i /proc/1/root/.)" ] && echo "I'm in a chroot" || echo "main system"
```

And if so, simply type `exit` to quit.